ffmpeg ignores input svg files resolution and produces 100x100 video
I have used this command for some years to produce .ogg files (or any other format) from a series of .svg files on Linux:
ffmpeg -y -r 1.2 -i %06d.svg -qscale:v 10 path.ogg
It has worked flawlessly until now, when it produces a video with 100x100 resolution, rather then the 1920x1080 resolution of the input files.
If I force the output resolution to be 1920x1080 using the -s option, the resulting video is a magnified version of the 100x100 video output I obtain without the -s option.  If I convert the svg files to png using inkscape everything is well, but I'd like to avoid making my workflow more complex.
Here you can find some of the .svg files.
Any ideas?

The issue is not reproducible. I have downloaded your 6 SVG files, executed your exact command, and the resolution of path.ogg is 1920x1080. I tested using FFmpeg 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 (the default version of Ubuntu 20.04). exiftool shows View Box: 0 0 1920 1080 for all the 6 SVG files. Maybe the issue is related to other files you have, and maybe it's related to the version of FFmpeg (or the version of librsvg).

ffmpeg version 7.0.2-3ubuntu1 → 100x100

It looks like there is a problem, probably with librsvg. ffmpeg on older boxes works, and so does on recent Ubuntu. I'll file a bug with Debian, thanks for trying. This is ffmpeg 7.1.3 on Debian trixie with librsvg 2.59.1+dfsg-1

It looks like there is a bug in newer versions (like 7.1) of FFmpeg (or maybe in librsvg).
We may force the output resolution using -width and -height and -keep_ar 0 arguments:
ffmpeg -y -width 1920 -height 1080 -keep_ar 0 -r 1.2 -i %06d.svg -qscale:v 10 path.ogg

In case we like to get the resolution of the SVG file, we may execute:
exiftool 000001.svg, and get: View Box: 0 0 1920 1080.
(Note that executing ffprobe 000001.svg shows 100x100, so we can't use FFprobe).

Note: Using older version of FFmpeg (like 4.2.7), the original command is working fine, and FFprobe shows 1920x1080.
